# Android how to convert int to String?

Tags: android

I have an int and I want to convert it to a string.  Should be simple, right?  But the compiler complains it can't find the symbol when I do:

```
int tmpInt = 10;
String tmpStr10 = String.valueOf(tmpInt);
```

What is wrong with the above?  And, how do I convert an int (or long) to a String?

Edit: valueOf not valueof ;)

Comment: valueOf big OOOOO

Comment: should be String.valueOf(tmpInt) (note the "O")

Comment: Yes, I see.  Typo on my part.  Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you do this String tmpStr10 = tmpInt+""; 
Simply concatenating an empty string at the end.

Answer (score 259, accepted):

Use this `String.valueOf(value);`

Answer (score 34):

Normal ways would be `Integer.toString(i)` or `String.valueOf(i)`.

```
int i = 5;
String strI = String.valueOf(i);
```

Or

```
int aInt = 1;    
String aString = Integer.toString(aInt);
```

Answer (score 16):

You called an incorrect method of String class, try:

```
int tmpInt = 10;
String tmpStr10 = String.valueOf(tmpInt);
```

You can also do:

```
int tmpInt = 10;
String tmpStr10 = Integer.toString(tmpInt);
```

Answer (score 8):

Use `Integer.toString(tmpInt)` instead.